# jplayer in drupal 7 preloads the audio

Tags: javascript

There is a content type called `song` and it has a file fields. I'm going to add a player on website using jplayer. the problem is, it preloads all of the songs. I mean all of the songs in the page are loaded with the page while I want it to be loaded when the user clicks on the play button. any idea or alternative for jplayer?

Comment: Why don't you use medial element module ?

Comment: @Soheil what is media element player? (az che playeri estefade konam?)

Answer (score 1):

try to use [MediaElement](https://drupal.org/project/mediaelement) and library [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)
simply install and enable it and put the library in sites/all/library/mediaelement .

Creat content type and add song/video field then go to manage display anad select which type of media you want (Song or Video)
That's it , you're done
let me know what's happen ;)

Comment: NOP! again downloads and loads audio on page load!